# On Transact-SQL: possible to build a statement to create a new column while using the data of another column all from the same table.

Tags: c#, sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

On Transact-SQL: Would like to create a statement that adds a column to my current active table, the newly added column would take data from another column of the same table. It will add the data on each row and sum it up on the new column.

To be more specific,

I work for a company that produces Sweet Potato fries, we use labels to describe the content of each box.

I have a table that gets updated and populated when a label gets printed, the label goes on each box; So number of labels == number of boxes we produce. The table has a column that describes the weight of each box; the column being named [CaseWeight].

I want to take this CaseWeight column do a Sum([CaseWeight]) on a new column and call it total pounds. While still been able to see the rest of the columns in the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a view with a window function:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*, sum(weight) over () as total_pounds
    from t;
```

You cannot put a window function in as a generated column, so this is probably the best approach.

Comment: Well I was thinking of maybe taking another approach, possibly using a join e.g "Self Join". It allows me to join the table with itself. But I'm not all that familiar with creating "self join" statements so I am a little confused on what that would look like.

Comment: @BayronPerdomo . . . A self-join is unnecessary.  Window functions are usually faster.

Answer (score 0):

To add a column to a table, you may need to drop the table, depending on the server settings. What I do in that case is back the data of the table up into another table (SELECT * INTO MyTableBackup FROM MyTable). Then I drop the table and recreate it with the new column (NOTE: When dropping and recreating the tables, don't forget to recreate the indexes and keys as well!). Then I do an insert from the backup table to the new one. You would do the Group By on the insert when summing. So if you wanted the sum of the weight of each package in the order, you would do:

```
    SELECT SUM(CaseWeight) AS TotalPounds FROM MyTableBackup GROUP BY OrderNumber
```

You can put that in the middle of the select like this:

```
    INSERT INTO MyTable
    SELECT
        bak.OrderNumber
        ,bak.NumberOfCases
        ,bak.CaseWeight
        ,(SELECT SUM(CaseWeight) FROM MyTableBackup b WHERE b.OrderNumber = bak.OrderNumber GROUP BY OrderNumber) AS TotalPounds
    FROM MyTableBackup bak
```

Just make sure you test the select part of your query before doing the DROP and INSERT.

Comment: Also, just to preface this with the obvious - MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A VALID BACKUP BEFORE DOING ANYTHING LIKE THIS!